# How to increment notifications when different buttons are clicked on multiple pages in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of buttons. When a user clicks on one it will add and show you a notification bubble. This calculates how many times a user clicked a button. This works fine for the table, as shown below.

However I have more buttons on a different part of a page that I also want to include in to the notification list. For example, if I have the button `pants` and O clicks on it, it must check the current notifications to see if any one of them is clicked and add to it, and vice versa.

How can I achieve this?

```js
function countN(counter) {
  if (counter > 0) {
    $('.notify').addClass("notification");
    $('.market-odds .btn').addClass("notification")
    $('.market-odds .btn').html(counter);
    $(".notify").html(counter);
  }
}

$('body').on('click', '.marketoptionrow.OP a.button', function() {
  var alreadyClicked = $(this).hasClass('clicked');
  if (!alreadyClicked) {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    var counter = parseInt($(".notify").html()) || 0
    counter++;
    countN(counter);

  }
});
```

```css
.notification {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 8px;
  /*height: 9px;*/
  line-height: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #b60000;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  width: 56px;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  background: url(images/odds_button.png) #f9b108 repeat-x;
  color: #005081;
  border-radius: 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px #f9b108 solid;
  border-top: 1px #f9b108 solid;
  border-bottom: 1px #f9b108 solid;
  border-right: 1px #f9b108 solid;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #005081;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Roboto-Bold';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="notify"> Notification</span>
<br/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Current</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="marketoptionrow OP" dataid="35917931">
      <td><a class="button" bettype="W">Milk</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="marketoptionrow OP" dataid="35917934">
      <td><a class="button" bettype="W">Salt</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="marketoptionrow OP" dataid="35917933">
      <td><a class="button" bettype="W">EGGS</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="marketoptionrow OP" dataid="35917937">
      <td><a class="button" bettype="W">flour</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br/> 

How do i include this into the notifications. if this is clicked first before the table buttons then the table buttons must add to its list and vice versa
<div id="">
  <div class="market">
    <input type="button" id="1104263 " class="btn btn-betslip bg-blue" value="Pants">
  </div><br/>
  <div class="market">
    <input type="button" id="1104264" class="btn btn-betslip bg-blue" value="Shirt">
  </div><br/>
  <div class="market">
    <input type="button" id="1109306" class="btn btn-betslip bg-blue" value="Shoes">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just change the selector to select all elements..? `'.marketoptionrow.OP a.button, .btn-betslip'`